# Installing SFML on CodeLite using Mac

Tags: c++, sfml, codelite

I am on a Mac using CodeLite for C++ and am trying to install the SFML library. I followed a tutorial (found here: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=18820.0) and I get the following error after doing everything the tutorial say:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libsfml-graphics.2.5.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/willbur/Desktop/School/CompSci142/SFML- 
Demo/Debug/SFML-Demo
 Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I copied all the .dylib files to the debug folder and I still get the error. The SFML version is the 2.5 MacOS Clang.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After running into this same issue I deleted my downloaded version of SFML and re-installed using Homebrew

```
brew install sfml
```

Homebrew will automatically put the sfml folders at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/{installed_version_number}/
```

From here setup your project in the same manner as in the listed tutorial you followed except replacing the Compiler Include Paths with:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/{installed_version_number}/include
```

and the Linker Libraries search path with:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/{installed_version_numer}/lib
```

You can also follow along with this resource to get it setup: [SFML with CodeLite on Mac OS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-ENN5zkF_s)